# CSS pie not working in IE 8, but working in IE 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, css3pie

I am using the following code for border radius:

```
.box {
     width:250px;
     height:250px;
     background:#ce0000;
     border-top-left-radius: 15px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
     border-top-right-radius: 15px;
     behavior:url(images/PIE.htc);
}
```

It worked fine in IE 9. But it's not working in IE 8. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: border radius not supported in ie8 and less versions of ie

Comment: @sasi Check CSS3Pie and see. That's what pie do, it adds this feature to IE.

Comment: I feel that the `images/PIE.htc` is not accessible. Can you put in your folder structure and file structure?

Comment: Sometimes position relative helps in IE8, please try it (it seems silly but has worked for me in the past - for reasons not known to me)

Comment: Folder and file structure is  correct  @praveen Kumar

Comment: I tried Position relative.but it not helped.

Comment: Also, does the parent element have overflow:hidden?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the position relative. But it not helped...

Comment: By shorthand It Working.Thanks all for helping and saving my time.

Answer (score 3):

Per the docs, PIE only supports shorthand border-radius rules:

> For all CSS properties which PIE parses, only the shorthand versions of those properties will be recognized. For example, while
>   border-radius is supported, the individual longhand
>   border-top-left-radius etc. properties are not.
>
> The reason for this is the same reason URLs are not resolved relative
>   to the CSS file (see above): PIE does not have visibility into where
>   each style property comes from. If there is both a shorthand and a
>   longhand property present, PIE cannot determine the order in which the
>   CSS author specified those properties, nor can it determine the
>   specificity of the selector for each property. It cannot therefore
>   make an informed decision about which property should take precedence.
>
> To avoid making dumb guesses, we have opted to only support shorthand
>   properties. Shorthand was chosen over longhand to keep file size small
>   and avoid tedious repetition.

http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#shorthand

So try changing your CSS to this:

```
.box {
     width:250px;
     height:250px;
     background:#ce0000;
     border-radius : 15px 15px 5px 5px;
     behavior:url(images/PIE.htc);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it working now with the shorthand code                 .box {
     width:250px;
     height:250px;
     background:#ce0000;
     border-radius : 15px 15px 5px 5px;
     behavior:url(images/PIE.htc);
}